# Selected Tabbar padding issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating sample project in swift. I have added tabbar controller in this project. I have set selectionIndicatorImage to highlight selected tab. I'm getting extra padding in selected tab.

Here is code for highlight selected tab :

```
let numberOfItems = CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count)
let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: (tabBar.frame.width / numberOfItems), height: tabBar.frame.height)
tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: UIColor(red:123.0/255.0, green:31.0/255.0, blue:162.0/255.0, alpha:1.0), size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
```

With the use of above code I'm getting output like this,

[image]

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

There is some default spacing while you select any `UITabBar`. To overcome below are the two solutions you can go with it.

> Solution 1:

You can change `UITabBar` x-origin slightly to left:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame = self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.insetBy(dx: -2, dy: 0)
```

> Solution 2:

```
self.tabBarController!.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -2, 0, 0)
```